# Prove $e^x$ maps onto $(0, +\infty)$ using group theory

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, group-theory, exponential-function

Let $\mathbb{R}^+$ be the real numbers under addition and let $\mathbb{R}^{*}$ be the nonzero real numbers under multiplication so that $(0, +\infty) \leq \mathbb{R}^{*}$. Suppose there is a group homomorphism $\exp : \mathbb{R}^+ \to (0, +\infty)$, namely $x \mapsto e^x$. With the fact that $\exp$ is strictly increasing, it's easy to see that $\exp$ is injective. To prove that $\mathbb{R}^+ \cong (0, +\infty)$, we could show that $\exp$ is continuous with $\lim_{x \to -\infty} e^x = 0$ and $\lim_{x \to +\infty} e^x = +\infty$ and then apply the intermediate value theorem. Is there an alternative way to prove $\exp$ is surjective using group theory?

---

I had ideas about using the correspondence theorem (if $G, G'$ are groups and $\varphi : G \to G'$ is a surjective homomorphism, then there is a bijection between the subgroups of $G'$ and the subgroups of $G$ containing $\ker \varphi$) and the fact that $(0, +\infty)$ is the [only subgroup of $\mathbb{R}^{*}$ with finite index](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/366207/determine-all-subgroups-of-mathbbr-that-have-finite-index), but these don't seem to be going anywhere.

Comment: This is a good question to ask. My thought is that the answer is probably "no." Surjectivity of the exponential function is an "analytic" statement, and I feel like algebra does not really offer you this sort of information. Maybe someone will prove me wrong though :-).

Comment: @jskattt797 In a context which explicitly involves positive real numbers -- a typical notation for the set of which being $\mathbb{R}_{+}\colon=[0, \infty)$ -- the syntax $\mathbb{R}^+$ is not too inspired. Also, your objective is not too clearly formulated. Are you assuming the existence of an injective morphism of *totally ordered* groups from $(\mathbb{R}, +, \mathrm{O})$ to $\left(\mathbb{R}_{+}^{\times}, \cdot, \mathrm{O}_{|\mathbb{R}_{+}^{\times}}\right)$?, where by $\mathrm{O}$ I am referring to the standard order relation on $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @ΑΘΩ I agree, do you have a suggestion for better notation besides $(\mathbb{R}, +)$? I'm assuming that $e^{x + y} = e^x e^y$, $e^x > 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, and $x < y \implies e^x < e^y$ when viewing $x \mapsto e^x$ as a map from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. Then define $\mathbb{R}^+$ and $\mathbb{R}^*$ and consider the map $\phi : \mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}^*$ induced from $\exp$. Since $\exp$ is injective, $\phi$ is also injective. Now I want to prove that $\phi$ is surjective.

Comment: @jskattt797 As far as referring to the additive group structure $(\mathbb{R}, +)$ by means of solely the support set $\mathbb{R}$ -- according to an abuse of notation and language that is ubiquitous throughout algebra (and not only) -- I would shy away from introducing any dubious abbreviations and would make sure to either 1) explicitly refer to the additive group $\mathbb{R}$ by employing such a syntagm of natural language or 2) to explicitly refer to the entire additive structure $(\mathbb{R}, +)$ in more formal settings.

Comment: @jskattt797 As for your original question -- which is profoundly nontrivial -- one can prove the following result: if $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}_+^{\times}$ is a group morphism increasing on an open interval $(a, b)$ with $a<b$, then $f$ is either trivial or an exponential of strictly superunitary basis. The proof will necessarily involve notions of continuity and ultimately the surjectivity of $f$ will follow from the fact that exponentials are surjective, fact at the heart of which lie topological properties, the circumventing of which is not possible and should not be contemplated.

Comment: I doubt that there is a proof using only group theory. Surjectivity must depend  on the topological structure of $\mathbb R$ since $\exp : \mathbb Q \to (0,\infty)$ is certainly not surjective.